# Django FilePathField Best Practice

Tags: django, django-models

I've looked over the questions in SO and none can explain the proper usage of Django's FilePathField.  The Django documentation about it is a little short. A web search does not yield good tutorials about it as well. To add do non uploaded files must be collected to the static directory,reside inside apps where they are used, or at the project level?

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://sharpe-s-django.blogspot.com/2009/09/uploading-files-via-django-application.html) (from 2009) `[...] There is also third type - FilePathField, but this cannot be used for uploading, only for selecting already uploaded files.` So I think this field can be used only for pointing to specific files (`match` property) i specific directory (`path` property). But I may be wrong as I've never ever used this field type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle uploaded files consider using FileField instead of FilePathField. FileField also stores path to the uploaded file, but it is designed to handle new file creation for uploads. FilePathField is just used to point to a path in your file system.